# 0x8badf00d exception short elapsed time

Tags: ios

I sometime get this error on the physical device with no debugger connected and is hard to reproduce:

```
Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
XXX failed to resume in time

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 1.060 (user 1.060, system 0.000), 5% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.003, 0% CPU
```

1. Is 1.060 seconds within the watch dog limit?
2. Is the timeout strictly within the method `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`? We don't use `didFinishLaunching` and we use a storyboard. Is the timeout from begin to end of the method?
3. Is it safe to assume all Facebook `FB Session` / `FBRequestConnection` calls do not happen in the main thread and are asynchronous?

How can I try to debug this because it is not always reproducible.

Comment: Are you using the TestFlight SDK < 2.0.1 by any chance?

Comment: Not using TestFlight.